# BASH : How to make a script that make "tail -f" always logging the last file in a directory, live

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading

I'm basically trying to make debugging easier for other scripts of mine.

(Centos 7.6)

What I need is a script doing :

1. tail -f the last file entry in a directory
2. if a new file appears in this directory, it logs this new file, smoothly
3. if I send a SIGINT (Ctrl+C), it doesn't leave orphans
4. with the less possible add-ons for the maximum portability

This is my non working solution :

```
CURRENT_FILE=`ls -1t | head -n1`
tail -n 100 -f "$CURRENT_FILE" &
PID=$!

while [ true ];
do
    #is there a new file in the directory ?
    NEW_FILE=`ls -1t | head -n1`
    if [[ "$CURRENT_FILE" != "$NEW_FILE" ]]; then
            #yes, so kill last tail
            kill -9 $PID
            clear

            #tail on the new file
            CURRENT_FILE=$NEW_FILE
            tail -n 100 -f "$CURRENT_FILE"
            PID=$!
    fi
    sleep 1s
done
```

The problem with this solution is that when I'm sending SIGINT (Ctrl+C), what I normally do when exiting a "tail -f", it leaves an orphan child in the background.
I've searched solution with "trap" but I don't get it well, and it doesn't seem to work with an eternal process like "tail -f".

I'll be glad to here your thoughts about that and get into advanced bash programming.

Comment: It seems you are missing an `&` at the end of `tail` command inside the `while` loop. Doesn't `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT` (at the beginning of script) solve the problem of child process in the background?

Comment: Note that `while [ false ]` will work just as well, but effectively demonstrates that this is the wrong way to write the loop.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you should probably explore `watch` instead.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Yes i am missing an `&` here, just a mistake when making the post, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes `while true` is the correct syntaxe

Comment: @tripleee `watch` does not work well with tail -f

Comment: No, I mean as a complete replacement for your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `trap` whenever the script exits and kill the process then. You don't need `-9` to kill your `tail` though, that's overkill.

You can also use `inotify` to tell you when something happens in the directory instead of sleeping and rechecking. Here's a basic building block. `inotify` has a lot of events you can wait for. You can add detection if the file was moved/renamed so you don't have to restart the `tail` in those cases etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

killpid() {
    if [[ -n $PID  ]]; then
        kill $PID
        PID=""
    fi
}

trap killpid EXIT

DIR="."

CURRENT_FILE="$(ls -1t "$DIR" | head -n1)"

tailit() {
    echo "::: $CURRENT_FILE :::"
    tail -n 100 -f "$CURRENT_FILE" &
    PID=$!
}

tailit

# wait for any file to be created, modified or deleted
while EVENT=$(inotifywait -q -e create,modify,delete "$DIR"); do
    # extract event
    ev=$(sed -E "s/^${DIR}\/ (\S+) .+$/\1/" <<< "$EVENT")

    # extract the affected file
    NEW_FILE=${EVENT#${DIR}/ $ev }

    case $ev in
        MODIFY)
            # start tailing the file if we aren't tailing it already
            if [[ $NEW_FILE != $CURRENT_FILE ]]; then
                killpid
                CURRENT_FILE="$NEW_FILE"
                tailit
            fi
            ;;
        CREATE)
            # a new file, tail it
            killpid
            CURRENT_FILE="$NEW_FILE"
            tailit
            ;;
        DELETE)
            # stop tailing if the file we are tailing was deleted
            if [[ $NEW_FILE == $CURRENT_FILE ]]; then
                echo "::: $CURRENT_FILE removed :::"
                CURRENT_FILE=""
                killpid
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: You're right, `-9` is not necessary. Thank you for your answer, I will check inotify inotifywait but it doesnt seems to be installed by default on centos

Comment: I accept your solution as the best one because you solved the trap problem and you actually spent time making it better.

Comment: Glad you like it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trap` solution at the beginning of your shell.

```
#! /bin/bash
trap ctrl_c INT
function ctrl_c() {
    if [[ -n "$PID" ]]; then
        kill -9 $PID
    fi
    exit 0
}

CURRENT_FILE=`ls -1t | head -n1`
tail -n 100 -f "$CURRENT_FILE" &
PID=$!

while [ true ];
do
    #is there a new file in the directory ?
    NEW_FILE=`ls -1t | head -n1`
    if [[ "$CURRENT_FILE" != "$NEW_FILE" ]]; then
            #yes, so kill last tail
            kill -9 $PID
            clear

            #tail on the new file
            CURRENT_FILE=$NEW_FILE
            tail -n 100 -f "$CURRENT_FILE" &
            PID=$!
    fi
    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: So, it works ! I understand `trap` better now; It also works with `trap ctrl_c EXIT` so i guess there is some kind of a hierarchy in signals, what I will check. Thank you.